# Consumir um resultado JSON (iniciante)

Tags: c#, json

Olá, tenho um teste bastante simples. Um método retorna um JSON(), mas como eu acesso os valores dentro deste retorno?

No método Teste gostaria de utilizar algum valor do JSON retornado. Poderiam auxiliar? Obrigado.

```
namespace DGBar.Controllers {
  public class TestController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Index() {
      return Json(new { Nome = "Rafael", Idade = 34 });
    }
    [Route("teste")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Teste() {
      var result = Index();
      return Json(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result).Nome);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Acho que não vai funcionar desse jeito... o método `Index()` vai retornar um HtttpActionResult e não o objeto que que você está tentando deserializar... você teria que fazer um request no método `Teste()` ou prepará-lo para receber o Json como parâmetro/argumento.

Comment: Obrigado pela força. Realmente precisei fazer alguns casts pra ter sucesso. Eis como consegui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui, mas não consegui utilizando classe anônima.

Segue o resultado.

```
[Route("teste")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Teste() {
  var result = Index();
  var contentResult = ((System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<TestController.Content>)result).Content;
  return Json(contentResult.Nome);
}
```

Comment: mas ainda assim não faz sentido... por que está acessando direto uma action que retorna um json para deseralizar e depois retornar outro JSON... o que vc está tentando fazer

Comment: Estou justamente tentando testar o resultado de um método que retorna um JSON. Dessa forma consegui retornar o JSON para o objeto original e aí sim consigo comprar as propriedades.

Answer (score -1):

Neste exemplo abaixo estou desserializando o json em um string

string result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);